# When units are destroyed by sword icons on house cards - how are the units chosen?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Say I have combat against an enemy that has two infantry and a knight on his territory. I use a house card that has two swords, and win the fight, and so two units are destroyed.

How the units chosen - do I choose which units are destroyed, or does the loser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The loser choses**. From [the rules](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/30/4f/304f72e3-4fe4-4f91-bfbe-75133161b092/va65_agot2_rulebook_web.pdf), page 21:

> When a player suffers casualties, he decides which of his units are removed (unless stated otherwise by the text ability of a played House card). Remember that supporting units can never be taken as casualties in combat.
>
> Note: Each casualty suffered destroys a single unit, regardless of Combat Strength. In other words, removing a Knight unit as a casualty still counts as only one casualty even though its Combat Strength is 2. For this reason, it is generally best to remove Footmen units as casualties, if able.